# Can I add URL/Link in web part settings (Sharepoint)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am creating a web part in SharePoint 2010. I know that we can add additional input fields (e.g. CheckBox, TextBox etc.) in web-part settings using specific attributes on the properties.

Now, is there any option to add a link that points to a webpage like to following mockup?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add in anything besides a checkbox (boolean) or text box (string), you need to do more work and create a custom [ToolPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.toolpart.aspx) object.  There is a good basis from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762727/custom-property-editor-for-web-parts-in-sharepoint) and here is some sample code that shows the basics of how to do this:

[image: Screen shot of simple tool part]

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;

namespace SharePointProject1.SimpleWebPart
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class SimpleWebPart : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart
    {
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            //Do the actual work of the web part here
        }

        public override Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPart[] GetToolParts()
        {
            //First add base tool parts and then our simple one with a hyperlink
            Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPart[] toolPartArray = new Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPart[3];
            toolPartArray[0] = new Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.CustomPropertyToolPart();
            toolPartArray[1] = new Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartToolPart();
            toolPartArray[2] = new mySimpleToolPart();

            return toolPartArray;
        }
    }

    //Implements a custom ToolPart that simply displays a link
    public class mySimpleToolPart : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPart
    {
        public mySimpleToolPart()
        {
            //You could pass this as a parameter to the class
            this.Title = "This is the title";
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink simpleLink = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink();
            simpleLink.Text = "Click on this Link";
            simpleLink.NavigateUrl = "http://www.google.com";
            Controls.Add(simpleLink);
            //Add some white space
            Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("p"));
        }
    }
}
```